# Override all operators in python

Tags: python, operators, overriding

I have a wrapper class for an object. I want it to apply all operations applied to it on the wrapped object, e.g `wrapper+=a` would yield the same result as `wrapped+=a`, for instance. I want to apply this for all operators. Any simple way to override all operators without overriding each one explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.  Though you could write an interface (probably as a decorator or base class) that makes this easy, if you need to do it more than once.  Or use one [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195601/override-all-operators-in-python/2195622#2195622) already.  (Guess I was 40s too late.)

Answer (score 6):

[ActiveState Code: Recipe 496741: Object Proxying](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741/)